# how to calculate framerate related to Images size

Tags: image-processing, camera, frame

I am working with a camera "Mikrotron EoSens MC1362", which has its own software, I have implemented an algorithm and want to create a program which captures data through the camera and does the processing in real time.

The problem is, in the original software I can see that the maximum Frame rate and shutter time will change whenever I am changing the image size, soI need to find a formula to related these parameters together.

For example, for image size (512x512) the maximum frame rate = 1733 and shutter = 2320 microsecond and for the full resolution (1280x1024) the maximum frame rate is = 430 and shutter time is 2319. Also the tap mode for the camera is 8x8. And the width for each image size must be a multiply of an 8.

Anybody has any idea how can I relate this parameter together in order to implement it in my code?

Comment: How about a discrete map? I.e. match all the possible combinations statically against its corresponding framerate.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, this depend on hardware specification because on higher resolution the CPU can calculate less images then lower resolution. In this case you have to calculate frames per second instead calculating resolutions. for example how much frames you get in one second will be frame-rate [framerate](http://documentation.apple.com/en/finalcutpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=D&section=1&tasks=true).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [camera's manual](http://www.g4.com.tw/web/file/product/usermanual/997-EoSens%203CL-MC1362-Manual.pdf) the camera is limited to a maximum framerate of 500 frames per second, and a maximum bandwidth (data rate) of 680 Mbytes/sec using the Camera Link interface.

Those two numbers should provide you with the boundary points of your calculations (e.g. at 1280 x 1024, you are limited by bandwidth to a theoretical maximum of around 520 frames per second, assuming 1 byte per pixel and no inter-frame overheads).

The shutter speed adds an extra delay, if you want it.

For example, at 512x512, you are not limited by data bandwidth, so at 500 frames per second (each frame is 1/500 seconds apart), your shutter speed is a minimum of 2,000 micro-seconds.

In practice there are probably a few overheads that you need to take into account, but the numbers above are theoretical limits to guide you.

Your (theoretical) equations are:

Minimum shutter time = 1/frame rate.
Maximum framerate = 1/(shutter time)

Actual framerate = 1/(shutter time + overheads)